# Smooth scrolling to anchor on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

After combing the forums and how-to guides, I have found a solution to a Smooth Scrolling problem that I had, but I'd like to ask some kind folks if the solution below will work for me before I try it, or if I'm missing something important.

I'm working on a live site and I don't want to create problems or break anything, so I'd like to be sure before I add the code below. I also know nothing about java or coding, so please forgive me if I don't use the right terms.

I want to enable smooth scrolling to an anchor on another page.
e.g. from my home page "domain.com/home", click the link, then
load the new page, e.g. "domain.com/contact"
and on loading the new page, smoothly scroll to the anchor, "domain.com/contact#section1".

Currently, it simply jumps, and I'd like to know if the steps below will enable the smooth scrolling.

I'm planning to:

1. Add the following codes to the website template's '' section (in the Joomla admin panel):

   ```
   <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   ```

I'm unsure whether this is necessary because I already use jQuery with some components, is it unnecessary to load jQuery again? Or will it not hurt to add this code regardless?

2. Then add this code to the same  section in the template:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" >
   $('html').css({
   display: 'none'
   });

   $(document).ready(function() {
   var hashURL = location.hash;
   if (hashURL != "" && hashURL.length > 1) {
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
   $('html').css({
     display: 'block'
   });
   smoothScrollTo(hashURL);
   } else {
   $('html').css({
     display: 'block'
   });
   }
   });

   function smoothScrollTo(anchor) {
   var duration = 5000; //time
   var targetY = $(anchor).offset().top;
   $("html, body").animate({
   "scrollTop": targetY
   }, duration, 'easeInOutCubic');
   } 
   </script>
   ```
3. As far as I know, this will enable the smooth scrolling, but I haven't added anything like 'smoothscroll.js' (which I've read a lot about) -- will that also need adding in the '' (after I upload it to the server), or is that included in the jQuery library?

I'm sorry if this seems very naive, I'm learning as I go. Thank you very much in advance to anyone who provides some feedback on this, I am truly grateful for your time and patience.

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Joomla already loads jQuery, so you do not need to load it again. I would either use a Joomla extension ([there is a free one here](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/qlsmoothscroll/)) or use a smooth scroll library ([like this one](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll)). Assuming you choose to do the latter, you just need to put the link in your Joomla template to the JS file and initialise it (this is all explained on the Github project page).

Both options are simple but if you don't have much experience in coding then the extension is probably the best way to go.

EDIT: To use smoothscroll on page load with the GitHub library, you will need to change your last function to:

```
function smoothScrollTo(anchor) {
    var scroll = new SmoothScroll();
    scroll.animateScroll(anchor);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jake. I tried the first plugin you mentioned but had no luck with it, not even for smooth scrolling on the same page. My question, though, is if I install the second smooth scrolling implementation (from Github), will the code I typed in the OP be enough to get the smooth scrolling code to work for anchors on other pages too?

Comment: It should work, but I have edited the question to give the function you will need to use if you want to make use of the GitHub library. On the third line, you can also specify an additional parameter to control the type of animation (information for this is on the project page).